# Merge into master. Merge shows on another branch, why?

Tags: git, git-merge

I suspect that this is misunderstanding on my part about how it git merge works.

I have three branches. master, range-filters and mvc-pages.

Master and mvc-pages are also on the remote called origin whereas the range-filters branch is only in my local repository.

Having completed work on the range-filters branch I merged it into master.

`git checkout master
git merge range-filters
git push origin master`

When I switch to the mvc-pages branch and pull.

`git checkout mvc-pages
git pull origin mvc-pages`

I now have the range-filters merged into the mvc-pages branch which I didn't expect. Is this the normal behaviour of git merge? Or have misunderstood this further?

Shouldn't the merged commits only show on the branch I've merged them into?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to replicate the described behaviour. Are you sure you used the correct branch names all the time?

```sh
#! /bin/bash
set -x
set -eu

dir=$$.$(date +%s)
mkdir $dir
cd $dir

mkdir remote
(   cd remote
    git init --bare
)

mkdir repo
cd repo
git init
git remote add origin ../remote

echo master > file.1
git add file.1
git commit -m 'file.1 added'
git push -u origin master

git checkout -b mvc-pages
echo mvc-pages > file.2
git add file.2
git commit -m 'file.2 added'
git push -u origin mvc-pages

git checkout -b range-filters
echo range-filters > file.3
git add file.3
git commit -m 'file.3 added'

git checkout master
git merge range-filters
git push origin master

git checkout mvc-pages
git pull origin mvc-pages
cat file.?
echo 'No range-filters here!'
git status
git log

cd ../..
rm -rf $dir
```

If you modify the last pull to

```
git pull origin master
```

(which was your mistake), all the branches end up in the same commit. You pull the changes from origin's master into your branch, that's why they're now there. The remote `mvc-pages` should still be OK, though.

Comment: Brilliant, that is reassuring. This means something else must be at work. Having looked over my terminal history that only thing I've left out is that whilst on the branch "mvc-pages" I did "git pull origin master" could this have an impact on the current selected branch?

Comment: @PaulSaunders: Yes, if I modify the script in this way, all the branches end up in the same commit. You pulled the changes from origin's master into your branch, that's why they're now there. The remote `mvc-pages` should still be OK, though.

Comment: Brilliant that makes good sense!! Can you add this to your reply and I'll mark it as answered!!